# structure data for different queries

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning firebase and trying to find the best way to structure my data.

Use an example of a simple leave application. Employees can submit and view their leaves. Managers can approve leaves.

**Option 1**

```
"leaves": [
{
  "employee": "pCIUfttSrXQ1dLPDwH7j9GExCkA2",
  "date": "2017-03-01",
  "status": "pendingApproval",
},
{
  "employee": "YSJCAe4wZdYCplA3e0ejMqzQmEF3",
  "date": "2017-01-01",
  "status": "approved"
}]
```

With option 1, filtering will be required in both cases:

- When employee lists his leave history (filter by "employee")
- When manager lists all the pending leaves (filter by "status=pending")

**Option 2**

```
"leaves":
{
  "pCIUfttSrXQ1dLPDwH7j9GExCkA2" : [
  {
    "date": "2017-03-01",
    "status": "pendingApproval"
  }
  ],
  "YSJCAe4wZdYCplA3e0ejMqzQmEF3" : [
  {
    "date": "2017-01-01",
    "status": "approved"
  }
  ]
}
```

With option 2, no filtering is required when employee lists his leave history, but filtering is required (and I don't know how) for manager to list pending leaves.

What should be the right way to structure the data? And if it's option 2, how would we filter the pending leaves for all employees?

Answer (score 1):

Use the second option;

For the manager to filter through the pending queries , use:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("leaves").queryOrdered(byChild: "status").queryEqual(toValue: "pending").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snapshot) in


        print(Snapshot.value!)


      // If you have multiple pending request you gotta loop through them        
      // using for loop, access them as separate entity and operate on them

    })
```